# How to scrape from a span subclass using scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

```
<span class="price-box"> <span class="price"><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> <span dir="ltr" data-price="16999">&nbsp;16,999</span>  </span>  <span class="price -old "><span data-currency-iso="PKR">Rs.</span> <span dir="ltr" data-price="50000">&nbsp;50,000</span>  </span> </span>
```

Hello. I need some help in extracting the "data-price with "span dir = ""ltr"". I cannot determine how to extract it using scrapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple (assuming you get this HTML with a response in spider callback):

```
>>> response.css('span[dir=ltr]::attr(data-price)').extract()
['16999', '50000']
```

I would recommend you to read about [Scrapy Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

Comment: @IbraheemNadeem if it helped you, then could you please upvote the answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @Stasdeep's answer, you could use xpaths:

```
response.xpath('//span[@dir="ltr"]/@data-price').extract()

//               -> Any sub span, no matter how deep it is
span[@dir="ltr"] -> span with attribute dir equaling "ltr"
@data-price      -> same level attribute you want
```